# ¿Cómo autoajustar automáticamente el tamaño de un donut chart de chartist.js?

Tags: javascript

Es la primera vez que trabajo con [chartist.js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html) (así se llama la librería), y uso una gráfica `donut`, la cual la muestro de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth">
    <div class="año" id="outer" ></div>
    <div class="año" id="inner"></div>
    <div class="año" id="inner1"></div>
    <div class="año" id="inner2"></div>
    <div class="año" id="inner3"></div>
</div>
```

Cada `div` de la clase año lo muestro después de hacer ciertas validaciones en los datos, cada `div` se muestra de acuerdo a si cumple la validación usando un ciclo `IF` para comprobar,

```
<script>
if (uno==dos){
    alert("ambos son true");
}
else{
    var chart = new Chartist.Pie('#inner3', {
                                                 series: [20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,10,10,10],
                                                 labels: <?php echo json_encode($labelArr); ?>,
                                            },
                                            {
                                                 donut: true,
                                                 showLabel: true,
                                                 donut: true,
                                                 chartPadding: 280
                                             })
}
```

Mi problema es que **quiero auto-ajustar** el tamaño de los **rings** de la gráfica **(DONUT)**, ya que en ocasiones solo por la validación de los ciclos solo se muestra el más pequeño y si es así quiero que se haga del tamaño más grande para que se visualice mejor, pero no he logrado hacerlo ya que al parecer mi problema es en la propiedad `chartpadding` pero no sé cómo hacerla automática, y ahorita solo hago que se logren acomodar los 5 div en forma correcta con esa propiedad de `chartpadding` o alguna otra forma de hacer que se haga grande, como lo mencione antes, si aparece uno que se haga grande y así sucesivamente pero si aparecen los 5 entonces que ninguno se haga grande y mantengan su tamaño.

No sé si alguien tiene la idea de con qué método puedo realizar eso y es que como se daran cuenta cada aro de la gráfica es un `DIV`.

En la imagen se nota un pequeño donut, el cual es el mas pequeño pero quiero que cuando se muestre solo ese se haga grande ocupando el espacio en blanco que se logra a ver, por que todo ese espacio en blanco son los demás DIVS que están ocultos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la segunda imagen se muestra cuando están todos los divs mostrando información, quiero que el mas pequeño vaya ocupando el siguiente div si el que sigue esta vació y así sucesivamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se exactamente que es lo que quieres hacer, si agregas algunas imágenes seria de ayuda, pero te anexo un ejemplo de como cambiar tamaño utilizando css:

```js
$("#resize").click(function(){

  var valor = Math.random() * (600 - 50) + 50;
  console.log(valor);
  $(".ct-chart").css('width',valor + 'px');
  $(".ct-chart").css('height',valor + 'px');
  
  new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', {
    series: [20]
  }, {
    donut: true,
    donutWidth: 60,
    donutSolid: true,
    startAngle: 270,
    showLabel: true
  });

  
});

new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', {
  series: [20]
}, {
  donut: true,
  donutWidth: 60,
  donutSolid: true,
  startAngle: 270,
  showLabel: true
});

new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart2', {
  series: [20, 10,4,6,7,3,12]
}, {
  donut: true,
  donutWidth: 60,
  donutSolid: true,
  startAngle: 270,
  showLabel: true
});

new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart3', {
  series: [20, 10]
}, {
  donut: true,
  donutWidth: 60,
  donutSolid: true,
  startAngle: 270,
  showLabel: true
});


/*
if (uno==dos){
    alert("ambos son true");
}
else{
  var chart = new Chartist.Pie('#inner3', {
  series: [20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,10,10,10],
  labels: {},
  },
    {
    donut: true,
    showLabel: true,
    donut: true,
    chartPadding: 280
    })
}
*/
```

```css
body{
  background-color: white!Important;
}

.ct-chart{
  width: 550px;  
  height: 550px;
}

.ct-chart2{
  width: 350px;  
  height: 350px;
}

.ct-chart3{
  width: 100px;  
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/scripts/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="resize">Resize</button>
<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth">
</div>

<div class="ct-chart2 ct-perfect-fourth">
</div>


<div class="ct-chart3 ct-perfect-fourth">
</div>
```

Comment: Claro, creo que tu respuesta me ayuda demasiado... me da una mejor idea de como puedo resolverlo o algo asi y claro, tambien te enxo en mi pregunta la imagen para que me entiendas, disculpa si no me exprese adecuadamente al formular la pregunta, de antemano gracias por tu respuesta